# Quartz 2.6.2 and .NET Core? - Error "Could Not Initialize DataSource"

Tags: configuration, datasource, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net-2.0

I'm using an older version of Quartz.NET (v2.6.2) with .NET Core (or possibly .NET5). I'm getting an error when attempting to use the StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler.  All my configuration settings are within my appsettings.json where I populate a NameValueCollection with these values and inject them into my classes with DI.

```
["quartz.scheduler.instanceId"] = "instance_one",
["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz",
["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "5",
["quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold"] = "60000",
["quartz.jobStore.type"] = "Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX, Quartz",
["quartz.jobStore.useProperties"] = "false",
["quartz.jobStore.dataSource"] = "default",
["quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix"] = "QRTZ_",
["quartz.dataSource.default.provider"] = "SqlServer-20",
["quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString"] = quartzConn
```

I am using the StdSchedulerFactory like this, where Settings.Properties is that NameValueCollection which contains all the config settings:

```
var factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(Settings.Properties);
var scheduler =  factory.GetScheduler();
```

On the *GetScheduler* method, the error, "Could Not Initialize Datasource:  default" is thrown.

The crazy thing is this code works fine in a Framework 4.x project that uses a regular web.config to supply the configuration settings.  Also, when I change to use Quartz 3.X with my code above, with configurations in the appsettings.json works fine.  Seems that me mixing and matching both versions is causing an issue where Quartz doesn't know how to retrieve some value?

Is there a way to manually build my scheduler and not use the factory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've had to go back to Framework 4 and Quartz 2.6 to get them to play nicely together.  I can only get Quartz 3.x to work with .NET Core/5.  Stepping through the source code with dotPeek, Quartz 2.6 is using ConfigurationManager to pull web.config details that don't exist in Core/5.  At this point I don't remember if I tried to add  my own web.config file to this project or not, but I've since moved on.